# How to select values from two different tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables in my SQL Server database. The first is catgeories and second is products. There is a column categories_id in both tables.

HERE IS MY TABLE FOR CATEGORIES :

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | category | parent   |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | BOY      | 0        |
|  2 | GIRL     | 0        |
|  3 | SHIRT    | 1        |
|  4 | SKIRT    | 2        |
|  5 | JACKET   | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

TABLE : PRODUCTS

```
+-------+--------------+----------------------+
| id    | title        |PRICE | Categories    |
+-------+--------------+------+---------------+
| 1     | RED SHIRT    | 300  |     3         |
| 2     | blue SKIRT   | 500  |     4         |  
| 3     | jeans jacket | 500  |     3         |           
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Now I want to select the values from Products table for a particular category like BOY.

Comment: hint: use mysql join

Comment: Where's `SQL SERVER` tag?

Comment: select * from CATEGORIES  as C join PRODUCTS as P on C.id=P.Categories WHERE C.category LIKE '%BOY%';

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT pr.id,pr.title,pr.price from products AS pr
INNER JOIN CATEGORIES AS cat ON  cat.id=pr.Categories
WHERE cat.category='Boy';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT products.* FROM products INNER JOIN categories ON products.categories = categories.id WHERE categories.category LIKE '%BOY%';
```

Use this query..

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
SELECT * FROM tproducts WHERE categories = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tproducts
JOIN tcategories ON tcategories.id = tproducts.categories WHERE tcategories.category = 'BOY'
```

I don't know your table names so I just used tproducts and tcategories

Answer (score 0):

FOR this use join query Example:

```
select *(or you can get any column as you write name) from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id where table1.category='BOY';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no boy(1) ID in Categories(field) in PRODUCTS(table)

SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS 
ON CATEGORIES.id=PRODUCTS.Categories
WHERE CATEGORIES.category ='BOY'